# Insert text into SearchView query at current cursor position

Tags: android, kotlin

I was able to add a character at the end of the SearchView query string currently in the text field:

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.list_fragment_menu, menu)

    val search = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search)
    val searchView = search.actionView as? SearchView
    searchView?.isSubmitButtonEnabled = true
    searchView?.setOnQueryTextListener(this)
    binding.button1.setOnClickListener {searchView?.setQuery(searchView.query.toString() + "Ɣ",false)}
}
```

But how can I insert the character into query string at the current cursor position? In other words, how do I retrieve the current cursor position?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do it through the **EditText** and the **Editable**
to Get the **EditText** use this:

```
val editText = searchView.findViewById<EditText>(androidx.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text)
```

And to get the Cursor position use :

```
editText.selectionStart
```

And to Insert a text on the Cursor position you can use it like below :

```
 val editText = searchView.findViewById<EditText>(androidx.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text)
 

 btn_click_me.setOnClickListener {
       val editable = editText.text
       editable.insert(editText.selectionStart, "Test")// here to insert a text at the cursor position
     }
```